# Semantic UI react, render dropdown/modal only when it's visible?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Is there a way to delay rendering of content of dropdown/modal until it is open?

I see they are being rendered even if they are not visible until user clicks to see its contents.

Comment: You could set the css property `display: hidden`. It would still be rendered to the dom, but not visible. Or is that what you want to avoid?

Comment: yeah I want to prevent 'rendering'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Modal` component uses `Portal` for rendering content, while `Portal` renders something only if [it's open](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/v0.71.0/src/addons/Portal/Portal.js#L337). This means that the component already satisfies your conditions.

With the `Dropdown` component, it will be more difficult. You can control it yourself, but it means that you will need to process all events self-consciously and it will be not easy.

```
<Dropdown open={true} options={open && options} />
```